# Transactional replication in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional

When we altering any database objects at publisher, we have received below error messages.

> #table_name table - Unable to modify table.
>   Cannot drop the table #table_name because it is being used for replication.

How can we alter DB objects at publisher those are involved in replication (without deleting published articles)?

Anybody suggest us further.

Comment: I think you already have your answer, but a very fast google search reveals the following article by Microsoft on the changes you can't make while a table is in transactional replication. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx

Comment: Based on the error message, my guess is that your change script is implemented as a drop/recreate. Dropping replicated objects is forbidden (you'll get that error message every time).